# How to call the slideToggle() function on the nearest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu and in some **li** there are sub-menu, and there are 3 such nestings. I need that when clicking on the **li**, which contains the **ul** with the "sub-menu" class, the slideToggle () function works on the nearest sub-menu. I tried through closest() but didn't work. How can i do this?

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

[Menu structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYF24.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` goes up the DOM tree. The `ul` elements that you're trying to target are *children* of the `li` that's clicked, so you need to use `children()` instead:

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please tell me, now when I click on the menu opening 3 levels of nesting - 1 menu closes, and 3 menus open. If I open it again, then all are open at once.

Comment: How can I just close them one by one?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about that, making sure to include all the relevant HTML, JS and CSS in your snippet - not as images.